# nonlocal variable->IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code:

---

- ```
  def **make_Print_Driver_singelton_class**(): 
    counter=0 
    def **setcount**(): 
    nonlocal counter counte+=1
  ```

---

I get this error:

```
nonlocal counter
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

what is the problem?

Comment: And what is stopping you from fixing the indentation?

Comment: i dont know what is the problem

Comment: The problem is mentioned in the error message. Have you read it carefully?

Comment: i do not understand what is the problem. i am not so strong in english and python is new to me too.

Comment: Take any Python manual in any language you are strong in and read couple of chapters. Then you will definitely understand what the problem is. You're asking about basics of the language...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think the code has indentation problems.

```
def **make_Print_Driver_singelton_class**():
  counter=0
    def **setcount**(): 
      nonlocal counter
      counte+=1
```

Comment: It is a very bad answer because the code is not formatted and you don't say what the OP did wrong and how to fix it.